# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки Button, появлялись один label и четыре entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Вообщем, нужно чтобы при нажатие кнопки (button) под №п.п. Угол справа Большая длина Меньшая длина Угол слева, шли 1 label( где цифры 1,2,3....n и таких хоть скок) и entry (поля для ввода данных, я пометил красной фигурной скобкой),

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, попробуйте декомпозировать ваш комплексный вопрос. хотя бы на два: 1. как создавать элементы при нажатии кнопки. 2. как позиционировать создаваемые элементы. и если возникнут трудности при решении этих более простых задач, задавайте отдельные вопросы. а в текущем вопросе оставьте, пожалуйста, только один более конкретный (нажав [edit])

Comment: Скорее всего, мне нужно "как создавать элементы при нажатии кнопки."

Comment: ну вот и сосредоточьтесь на этом вопросе, внеся соответствующую правку (нажав [edit])

Comment: '''как создавать элементы при нажатии кнопки?''' делаете функцию, которая создаёт нужные элементы и привязыаете её к батону. например but.config(command=foo)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# В список table будем складывать поля ввода построчно,
# чтобы потом можно было получить к ним доступ по индексу и можно было обрабатывать циклом
# (например, table[0][1] - entry из первой строки и второго столбца)
# Заодно по длине списка можно определить, в какую строку grid-a элементы управления размещать
table = []

def add_row():
    row_number = len(table)+1  # +1 т.к. 0-ая строка grid уже занята шапкой, и нумерация по порядку идет с 1
    Label(text=row_number).grid(row=row_number, column=0)
    row = []
    for i in range(1, 5):  # i будет меняться 1 до 4 включительно
        entry = Entry()
        entry.grid(row=row_number, column=i)
        row.append(entry)
    
    table.append(row)

# Делаем шапку таблицы и кнопку добавления строк
Label(text="№ п/п").grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(text="Угол справа").grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(text="Большая длина").grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(text="Меньшая длина").grid(row=0, column=3)
Label(text="Угол слева").grid(row=0, column=4)

Button(text="Добавить строку", command=add_row).grid(row=0, column=5)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]